# How to solve a problem of array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

Suppose, there is a grid array of 5x5 consisting only of 1's and 0's(1's are ship and 0's are water). and we have the position of the bomb(1x1) and its blast radius. If have to determine how many ships are destroyed?

I have tried solving this using if-else and it shows correct answer for radius = 1 but shows wrong answer for radius = 2. And if someone have a smaller code, then that will be great.

```py
grid = np.array([[0,1,1,0,1],[0,0,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1,0]])
bomb_coordinate = grid[1][1]
radius = 1
ship_count = 0
a, b = 1,1

if a==0:
    if b == 0:
        for i in range(a, a+radius+1):
            for j in range(b, b+radius+1):
                if grid[i][j] == 1:
                    ship_count += 1
    elif b == 4:
        for i in range(a , a+radius+1):
            for j in range(b-radius, b+1):
                if grid[i][j] == 1:
                    ship_count += 1
    else:
        for i in range(a, a+radius+1):
            for j in range(b-radius, b+radius+1):
                if grid[i][j] == 1:
                    ship_count +=1
elif a == 4:
    if b == 0:
        for i in range(a-radius, a+1):
            for j in range(b, b+radius+1):
                if grid[i][j] == 1:
                    ship_count += 1
    elif b == 4:
        for i in range(a-radius , a+1):
            for j in range(b-radius, b+1):
                if grid[i][j] == 1:
                    ship_count += 1
    else:
        for i in range(a-radius, a+1):
            for j in range(b-radius, b+radius+1):
                if grid[i][j] == 1:
                    ship_count +=1
else:
    if b == 0:
        for i in range(a-radius, a+radius+1):
            for j in range(b, b+radius+1):
                if grid[i][j] == 1:
                    ship_count += 1
    elif b == 4:
        for i in range(a-radius , a+radius+1):
            for j in range(b-radius, b+1):
                if grid[i][j] == 1:
                    ship_count += 1
    else:
        for i in range(a-radius, a+radius+1):
            for j in range(b-radius, b+radius+1):
                if grid[i][j] == 1:
                    ship_count +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, it shortened my code and it gives perfect answer.

'''

```
grid = np.array([[0,1,1,0,1],[0,0,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1,0]])

new_grid = np.pad(grid, pad_width = 1, mode = 'constant', constant_values = 0)

radius = 1

bomb_coordinate = new_grid[1+radius][1+radius]

ship_count = 0

a, b = 1 + radius, 1+radius

for i in range(a-radius, a+radius+1):
    for j in range(b-radius, b+radius+1):
        if new_grid[i][j] == 1:
            ship_count += 1
```

'''

Here, padding function in numpy library worked magic.

Comment: I'm glad you solved the radius issue. Did you look at my answer at all? You still don't need the nested for loops. `if np.any(grid[a-radius: a+radius+1, b-radius: b+radius+1]):
    ship_count += 1` should be more efficient.